# Postgres: where json array contains (a subselect query of ids)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to put together a postgres query that checks to see if a json field with an array of `id`'s contains any id's from a subselect query. Eg: a typical `user` table looks like this:

```
User
  .id           // Int     --> 1
  .first_name   // String  --> Joe
  .last_name    // String  --> Doe
  .tags         // JSON    --> [4, 9, 21, 26, 39]
```

the tags table is this:

```
Tags
  .id           // Int     --> 1
  .name         // String  --> "Peaches"
```

But anyway, here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
select u.id, u.first_name from users u 
  where u.tags = any( array (
    select t.id from tags t where t.name in ('Peaches', 'Nuts and Honey', 'Flour')
));
```

This results in the following error:
`No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Any thoughts on how to fix this would be awesome!

Comment: If you're just storing a flat structure, why not use an `ARRAY` column? That prevents unexpected surprises.

Comment: I can honestly say i've never heard of a straight up `ARRAY` column. what is a column type for `array`?

Comment: It's a [Postgres feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html) if that's what you're using. You've inexplicably tagged this with MySQL as well.